# Three state UIButton in ios TableView List

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, threestate

I have students attendance list in `UITableView`. Where each cell having an `UIButton` to set student attendance like `Present`, `Absent` and `Leave` on button click. How can I achieve this on single button.

Comment: Why don't you use three separate buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have An `UIButton` in your `tableViewCell` then `add Target` to your `UIButton` and `set button Tag with indexPath.row` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like-

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    attendanceListTableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    cell.studentNameLbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Student %ld",(long)indexPath.row];

    cell.editBtn.tag=indexPath.row;

    [cell.editBtn setTitle:[attandanceArry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [cell.editBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(editAttendance:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}
-(void)editAttendance:(id)sender{

    UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)sender;

    if ([btn.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"P"]) {
        [btn setTitle:@"A" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [attandanceArry replaceObjectAtIndex:btn.tag withObject:@"A"];
    }else if ([btn.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"A"]) {
        [btn setTitle:@"L" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [attandanceArry replaceObjectAtIndex:btn.tag withObject:@"L"];
    }else if ([btn.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"L"]) {
        [btn setTitle:@"P" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [attandanceArry replaceObjectAtIndex:btn.tag withObject:@"P"];
    }

}
```

In this `attandanceArry` is `mutableArray` having all default value is `"P"` with `capacity` of your `number of students` and `editBtn` is your cell `UIButton`. Here I use `custom tableViewCell class` i.e. `attendanceListTableViewCell` class having `UIButton`. At the end you can use `attandanceArry` as result array when you complete editing attendance. I hope this will help you...:)

Comment: Happy to help you :) . If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by simply implementing the following `@selector` for your `UIButton` in `UITableViewCell`.

```
- (void)btnSetMode:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    if (btn.tag == 0)
    {
        [btn setTitle:@"Present" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btn.tag = 1;
        // Define your required task...
    }
    else if (btn.tag == 1)
    {
        [btn setTitle:@"Absent" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btn.tag = 2;
        // Define your required task...
    }
    else if (btn.tag == 2)
    {
        [btn setTitle:@"Leave" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btn.tag = 3;
        // Define your required task...
    }
    else if (btn.tag == 3)
    {
        [btn setTitle:@"Attendance" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btn.tag = 0;
        // Define your required task...
    }
}
```

Your single button will do all the required task as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Change the button title and background color when it's clicked. Personally, I would use three different buttons so that all different options would be visible at the same time. `UIPicker` is one option too.

Comment: you are right but according to my UI i have to use single button on eah cell

Comment: What you mean accoring to your UI? Can't you change the cell content to accommodate three buttons? And if you change the title and color you only need a single button.

Answer (score 0):

Is a `UISegmentedControl` what you are looking for?

[image: A UISegmentedControl]

See the Apple Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/index.html).  It can be configured in a storyboard with the correct number of segments and segment titles.  When the user selects a segment it will be highlighted, and any other segments are deselected.

Comment: I want to use single button having three state not segment Control. If i press button first time it show present, second time press show absent and third time press button show leave